# Multiple select statements not working but individually will (loop and case)

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, reporting-services, case

The below is my code, what I am trying to do is count the # of Saturdays vs # of Sundays vs # of Weekdays in a given dynamic date range - hence the loop.
I want to count the total net for each day and get the average net for the Saturday/Sunday/Weekdays for that date range.

When I run #1 and #2 separately, then I get the results correctly, but when I run together, I get null for #2, so the results are incorrect.

```
Declare @DespatchFrom datetime = '2021-08-01'
Declare @DespatchTo datetime = '2021-08-09'
Declare @SATcount int = 0
Declare @SUNcount int = 0
Declare @WKCount int = 0
```

-- #1 Loop through the days to get counts, in this case it returns 1 for Saturday

```
        while @DespatchFrom<=@DespatchTo
        Begin
            IF DATENAME(dw, @DespatchFrom) = 'Saturday'
                SET @SATcount=@SATcount+1
            ELSE IF DATENAME(dw, @DespatchFrom) = 'Sunday'
                SET @SUNcount=@SUNcount+1
            ELSE
                SET @WKCount=@WKCount+1
            SET @DespatchFrom=DateAdd(d,1,@DespatchFrom)
        END
    select @SATcount as SATCount, @SUNcount as SUNcount, @WKCount as WKCount
```

--#2 Get the total Net for the given day of the week, in this case Saturday returns 47.36

```
        Select SUM(CASE WHEN TranType = 'SRT' THEN (Net*-1) ELSE Net END) as SATNet
                from trans t
                where t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) 
                        and t.despatchDateTime <= DateAdd(d,1,(@DespatchTo))
                        and DatePart("w",t.Despatchdatetime) = 1
```

-#3 ultimately I like to get the average net for that day of the date range

```
        Select CASE WHEN @SATcount = 0 THEN 0  ELSE SATNet/@SATcount END
```

Comment: You don't need a loop to do this at all. A calendar table, or a Tally would be *far* more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

**We can do this without loops using a calendar table, and left-joining the table to it.**

You can use a real one, I will generate one on the fly using [Itzik Ben-Gan's tally function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1)

```sql
DECLARE @DespatchFrom datetime = '2021-08-01';
DECLARE @DespatchTo datetime = '2021-08-09';
SET @DespatchTo = DATEADD(day, 1, @DespatchTo);

WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 c FROM L0 a, L0 b, L0 c ),
    Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
              FROM L1 ),
    Dates AS (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day, @DespatchFrom, @DespatchTo) + 1)
          DATEADD(day, rownum - 1, @DespatchFrom) StartDate,
          DATEADD(day, rownum    , @DespatchFrom) EndDate
        FROM Nums
    )

SELECT
    v.DayOfWeek,
    SUM(v.NetAmount) Amount,
    AVG(v.NetAmount * 1.0) AvgAmount
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN trans t
    ON t.DespatchDateTime >= d.StartDate
    AND t.despatchDateTime < d.EndDate
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
   CASE WHEN TranType = 'SRT' THEN (Net * -1) ELSE Net END),
   CASE DATEPART(weekday, d.StartDate)
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Sat'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sun'
        ELSE 'Weekday'
   END
) v(netAmount)
GROUP BY v.DayOfWeek;
```

You may want to check the `DATEFIRST` setting before running this code.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface but it doesn't appear to be working